# Is there a good diagramming library for Python?

Tags: python, graph, diagram

I should say I'm looking for something interactive, equivalent to what Nevron offers in it's .NET Diagram product, where a user can create nodes, interact with them by dragging them around, etc. I know there's GraphViz, but as far as I know it's static, and just renders a graph/diagram, there is no interaction with it.

I have a bad feeling there is nothing as rich as this in the cross platform world for Python or any other script language, but maybe I've missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing graphviz dot files is a good way to go.  Google for graphviz and see http://code.google.com/p/pydot/ for a python wrapper.

Comment: OP specifically says "I know there's GraphViz, but as far as I know it's static, and just renders a graph/diagram, there is no interaction with it." Same situation here; GraphViz works great for viewing but not for editing diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

[Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/) is probably not what you want, but is still really excellent.

Comment: But does this enable user selection of the nodes? Far as I can tell it isn't interactive.

Comment: I apologize. I had remembered it being interactive in that way, but was wrong. Ubigraph is *not* what you want. :/

Comment: Ubigraph allows you to hook callbacks to double-click events on vertices, but it doesn't allow you to drag them. It's force directed layout is still pretty nifty though.

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for a solution to this myself for quite some time, and have just come across an Apache 2.0 licensed project based on Cairo and GTK, called [Gaphas](https://github.com/gaphor/gaphas).

It has diagram widgets allowing user placement and interaction, and appears to be quite active.

There's also a python-code generated diagram library (appropriately, and perhaps confusingly) called [Diagrams](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/), which you may be able to borrow from, though doesn't appear interactive.